# Хранение больших констант

Tags: c++, const

Хочу записать минимальное `__int64` число в константу:

```
static const __int64 Mint64=-9223372036854775808;
```

Выдает предупреждение:

> [Warning] integer constant is so large that it is unsigned

Как можно этого избежать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете использовать константу `INT64_MIN` из заголовочного файла `<stdint.h>`

Это всего лишь предупреждение, по умолчанию числовые константы считаются обычным `int`, либо `unsigned int`, и предупреждение выводится чтобы случайно не присвоить такое значение обычному 32-битному инту, но если же вам надо указать подобную константу и вы не хотите видеть предупреждение, то можно явно указать, что она имеет тип `long long`

```
static const __int64 Min64=-9223372036854775808LL;
```

Comment: А без подключения заголовочных файлов?

Comment: Это всего лишь предупреждение, чтобы случайно не присвоить такое значение обычному 32-битному инту, да и всё равно этот же файл уже включается многими стандартными, напримет тем же <iostream>, но можно явно указать что константа типа long long.